# phpexcel conditional formatting Icon Sets

Tags: php, html, phpexcel, pear

I have spent the last few days trying to look up how to use the built in icon sets instead of changing the background color for my conditional formatting. I am looking to use the green tick and red cross for my conditional formatting instead of a red and green background.

i am using the PHPEXCEL library to build the current spreadsheet but if necessary i will change my code to the PEAR library if needed.

i haven't found anything which has been of any help to me at this moment on any sites and i am hoping someone may have read something about how to do this? Or has some code which already does this... any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option of using icon sets not available: you can only set styling/formatting information such as number format, font, colour, borders. I didn't even realise that Excel gave that option with conditional formatting.
I suspect it's highly unlikely that PEAR will give you this option either.

The best alternative option that I can think of would be to use a custom number format mask that set colour and added special characters such as tick/cross.

**EDIT**

Example

Using number format masks: set font to Wingdings and format mask to

```
[Red][=0] "ý";[Green][=1] "þ"
```

A cell value of 0 will appear in Red as a box in a cross, a cell value of 1 will appear in Green as a tick in a box.

Comment: where would i place that peice of code in the conditnal formating for phpexcel?? would u happen to know at all cause the code for changing the color looks like this... {$objConditional1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getEndColor()->setRGB('F75D59');}

Comment: My example isn't using conditional formatting, it's using number formatting, and would be applied as any number formatting mask: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setName('Wingdings'); $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[Red][=0] "ý";[Green][=1] "þ"');